# List of objects vs string value comparison

Tags: java, hudson

I expecting the following to return true.

```
   public class HudsonJob {

     private String name;
     private String status;
     public String getName() {
      return name;
     }
     public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
     }
     public String getStatus() {
      return status;
     }
     public void setStatus(String status) {
      this.status = status;
     }

     public boolean equals(Object jobName) {
      return name.toLowerCase().equals(((String)jobName).toLowerCase());
     }

     public int hashCode() {
      return name.hashCode();
     }
    }
```

,

```
List<HudsonJob> existingJbsLst = hudsonUtil.getAllJobs(); // returns multiple HudsonJob objects in the list.
```

The statement I'm expecting to return true is :

`boolean isExistingJob = existingJbsLst.contains("AnExistingJOB");`
is always returning false.

OR 
 `boolean isExistingJob = existingJbsLst.equals("AnExistingJOB");` is also returning false.

What should I add/change in the code to get the expected return value.

Comment: You should either add null checks, or default initializers.. so your code doesn't crash on null

Comment: This is just a sample code , not the full code , please take the objective

Comment: Your example is confusing people.  Please explicitly show how you are doing the comparisons, and what types you are comparing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "contains" operator loops through all the memers of the set, and compares the "want" value to the "found" value. I say that very carefully. If you say "joblist.contains(wantjob)", this gives -- to leave out some complexity, the relevant part:

```
for (HudsonJob gotjob : joblist)
{
  if (wantjob.equals(gotjob))
    return true;
}
```

That is, the comparison is "objectIAmLookingFor.equals(objectInList)", NOT "objectInList.equals(objectIAmLookingFor)".

So when you search a list of HudsonJob's for a String, it is using the String.equals function, NOT your HudsonJob.equals function. And String.equals knows nothing about HudsonJobs, so it promptly returns false.

There are two ways to do what you want.

One way is to change your HudsonJob.equals function to

```
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
  if (o==null || !(o instanceof HudsonJob))
    return false;
  return this.name.toLowerCase().equals(((HudsonJob)o).name.toLowerCase());
}
```

Then write

```
HudsonJob wantjob=new HudsonJob();
wantjob.setName("AnExistingJob");
if (existingJobList.contains(wantjob))
  ... whatever ...
```

The other way is to not use "contains" but instead write your own search function, like:

```
public boolean jobInList(List<HudsonJob> existingJobs, String wantJob)
{
  for (HudsonJob gotjob : existingJobs)
  {
    if (gotjob.name.toLowerCase().equals(wantJob.toLowerCase())
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

(Actually if you need the toLowerCase it would be better to do the wantJob.toLowerCase before the loop, but whatever.)

Then you can say

```
if (jobInList(existingJobs,"AnExistingJob"))
... do something ...
```

Comment: How about adding toString() in HudsonJob class which returns the 'this.name'. So that contains method of list looks for "AnExistingJOB".equals(hudsonjob) --> hudsonjob's to string return the same as what I'm checking above and returns true. –

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. String.equals does not compare the String to the other object's .toString. It checks if the other object is a string, and if it isn't, it returns false. So String.equals(x) where x is not a String always returns false, period, end of story.

Answer (score 4):

You brake [the contract](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) for `equals` method. For example:
*It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.*
And in your case `job.equals(string)` may be true, but `string.equals(job)` will always be false.

And what probably happens in your list is that elements are compared another way:

```
for (Object el : list) {
    if (parameter.equals(el)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

That's the technical reason why it's not working: `"AnExistingJOB".equals(jobObject)` is always false.

**edit**
BTW, your `hashCode` method is wrong also. If comparing in `equals` method you ignore case, ignore it in `hashCode` too. **Bozho**'s advice is probably a good one: IDE will generate those methods better. Also, you can check **Andreas_D**'s answer for a valid implementation.

Answer (score 2):

- You should pass a `HudsonJob` object (not a `String`) to the `contains(..)` method. For example (if you add a constructor taking the name as parameter):

  ```
  boolean exists = existingJbsLst.contains(new HudsonJob("AnExistingJOB"));
  ```
- Let your IDE generate the `equals` and `hashCode` methods - it will add proper `null` checks, type checks, etc.
- You are breaking the contract of `equals`. [See here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)
- use `string.equalsIgnoreCase(..)`

Comment: Yes "AnExistingJOB" is an hudson job in my context , say

Answer (score 2):

The second expression really should return false, because you compare a List to a String. If the first expression returns false, then obviously there's no such job in the list. The implementation <strike>of equals is correct</strike> (OK, you should test for 'null' and for same classes)

While writing about the missing test - equals is not implemented correctly, it should not take a job name but a HudsonJob object:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (obj == null) return false;
  if (!(obj instanceof HudsonJob)) return false;
  HudsonJob that = (HudsonJob) obj;
  return this.name.equals(that.name);
}
```

Comment: You don't need the obj==null check as null instanceof HudsonJob is always false.

Comment: How about adding toString() in HudsonJob class which returns the 'this.name'. So that contains method of list looks for "AnExistingJOB".equals(hudsonjob) --> hudsonjob's to string return the same as what I'm checking above and returns true.